# Skipping folder in Camel S3 Consumer

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

Is there a way to **skip** reading folders in the S3 consumer? 
I have multiple routes consuming from a bucket, each using a different prefix. That way, they emulate reading from certain folders, but they end up consuming the "folder" itself, and then deleting it.

If there's no way to avoid reading it in, is there a way to avoid deleting these "folders"?

Answer (score 2):

Read header S3Constants.KEY(CamelAwsS3Key) to skip your folder.
Try this.

```
from(awsUri)
    .choice()
        .when(header(S3Constants.KEY).isNotEqualTo("{your-folder-name}/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem where camel-aws-s3 component reading folder itself when there is no object inside the folder. I resolved using filter with CamelAwsS3ContentLength header. if there is only folder then CamelAwsS3ContentLength is 0 otherwise will be the file size.

In this case use deleteAfterRead=false and delete the object manually after receive the file from AWS S3, if deleteAfterRead=true then camel will delete the folder also. Please find the code sample below

```
<route>
   <from uri="aws-s3:bucketName?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&amp;delay=10s&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;deleteAfterRead=false"/>

  <filter>
    <simple>${headers.CamelAwsS3ContentLength} > 0</simple>

    <setProperty propertyName="S3FileNameOnly"><!--get the fileName from CamelAwsS3Key header-->
        <simple>${header.CamelAwsS3Key.split("\/")[1]}</simple>
    </setProperty>

    <!--downlod the file in local location -->
    <to uri="file://localfolderlocation?fileName=$simple{headers.CamelAwsS3Key}" />
    
    <!--after downloading file delete the s3 object manually. Donot use deleteAfterRead=true -->
    <to uri="aws-s3:bucketName?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&amp;operation=deleteObject"/>

  </filter>
</route>
```